# Can I simply remove 'IBus Pinyin Setup'?

Tags: input-language

I am so happy with my Ubuntu 14.04LTS with all text mode booting and everything. In software center 'IBus Pinyin Setup' and doing some Internet surfing I found that it is about Chinese language and input method. Do I really need this software in my laptop?
I use English/English(US or UK).

And there is this 'IBus Bopomofo Preferences', why? why?

Answer (score 0):

Try it. If the system lets you remove it then remove it. You know you don't need it. Often other packages insist that completely unrelated stuff are dependencies, so just try and see what it says: it may insist on removing a whole load of packages that you really don't want to remove.

I removed all that garbage without any problems. Nice and clean.

Aside: It makes sense to install it "as default", but it would make more sense for the installer to ask if you would ever need or use it.

Comment: I could easily remove 'IBus Pinyin Setup' from software centre and the good news is 'IBus Bopomofo Preferences' also disappeared.